# Codeigniter: Don't Allow multiple users to register with same email

Tags: php, mysql, database, duplicates, codeigniter-3

When 2 or more user registering with same email on same time. It is passing server side validation and allowing to insert as there is no data when checked in DB using form validation

Even, I've tried to put code exactly above insert method

Don't want to modify database structure like add unique key or etc

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not add unique on email address?

Comment: There is some old data with duplicate entry of email in database table. and I've to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless the presence of a unique index on the email address field, it might still happen that a given email address is not there at the time of the check, but it's already there when trying to insert it.

One way to tackle this is to (write) lock the table before the check and release the lock after the insert. This will make the first check & insert to succeed, while other checks will have to wait until the first insert is done.